Test that a Dart stream does not emit anything, without listening to it
I am currently working on a Flutter app, but my question is solely related to Dart. I need to implement a repository which exposes an outbound stream of data. This repository's responsibility is to call the backend, transform the data, and emit the data in the outbound stream (note, this stream is actually a BehaviorSubject, because of the way to integrate this repository in the application overall architecture).
The repository needs to call the backend if and only if:

the user is logged in
AND
some "client" has listened to the repository outbound stream

whenever the user logs in or some "client" listens to the outbound stream.
(see example code below)
class Repository {
  Repository(
    {required this.backendClient}
  ) {
    streamController = BehaviorSubject<DataModel>(
      onListen: () {
        conditionallyCallBackend();
      }
    );
  }

  final BackendClient backendClient;
  late final BehaviorSubject<DataModel> streamController;
  bool isAuthenticated = false;

  void conditionallyCallBackend() {
    if(isAuthenticated & streamController.hasListener) {
      callBackend();
    }
  }

  void callBackend() async {
    await backendClient.callBackend();
    streamController.add(DataModel());
  }

  void onUserLogin() {
    isAuthenticated = true;
    conditionallyCallBackend();
  }
}

This implementation covers my requirements well, but I am having trouble testing those rules, especially when I want to verify that nothing has been emitted in the stream.
See the following test, which fails:
void main() {
  group("test rules", () {
      late Repository repository;
      late BackendClient backendClient;

      setUp(
        backendClient = MockClient();
        repository = Repository(backendClient: backendClient);
      );

      test("stream does not emit if not listened to (even if logged in)", () {
          repository.onUserLogin();
          unawaited(expectLater(repository.streamController.stream, neverEmits(anything));
        }
      );
    }
  );
}

This test fails, because the expectLater function listens to the stream as a side effect. Therefore, conditionallyCallBackend if clause is true, callBackend is called and data is emitted through the stream.
How would one test that nothing has been emitted through the stream without listening to it? Is the fact that this test is difficult to write a smell that my implementation is incorrect?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Only broadcast streams can emit events with no listeners, so your test can just verify that the stream is not a broadcast stream.  If that's not sufficient, then you can modify your Repository class to add some mechanism for observers to tell if conditionnallyCallBackend [sic] has been called.

Thanks for your insight James! However, BehaviorSubjects seem to actually be broadcast streams (https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html). What I wanted is to check in my tests is the overall behavior of the Repository class (data emitted to stream and calls to backend client), not whether the "internal" methods have been called.

Perhaps modify your Repository to allow tests to pass a mocked StreamController, and then you could verify that that no events were added to that mock?
